# ContactsApp Performance

Tags: google-apps-script

Doing some testing on google script's ContactsApp and loading in contacts.  It looks like it takes as much time to run ContactsApp.getContacts() (loading all contacts) as it does to run ContactsApp.getContact('email') (specific contact).  About 14 seconds on each method for my contacts

My assumption is that both methods are calling all contacts and the 2nd only matches on email.  This drags quite a bit.

Has anyone confirmed this and is there anyway to keep the loaded contacts in memory between pages (session variable?).

Comment: I realize that I answered your cache question and not the original question - sorry!

Comment: I have noticed same issue . If you have many contacts (>5000) it can take 40 seconds to respond.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few options for storing per-user data:

- If it's a small amount of data, you can use [User Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_userproperties)
- You can store much more data using [ScriptDb](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb), but this will be global, so you'll have to segment off user data yourself
- If you only need the data for a short amount of time, say, between function calls, you can use the [Cache Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_cache). You'll want to use [getPrivateCache()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_cacheservice#getPrivateCache)

It sounds like for your use case getPrivateCache() is your best option for user specific session-like data storage.

(Just make sure your intended use fits within the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/terms/).)