# ContactsApp.getContactsByName is very slow

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on, google-contacts-api

I am using ContactsApp in Google Drive Add-On to fetch contacts when user types in input box .
If I have many contacts ContactsApp.getContactsByName responds very slowly . I have around 5000 contacts and this method takes around 40 seconds to respond. I logged the times to test. One of my clients has around 20,000 contacts and he cannot see results of search. How can we improve performance of ContactsApp.getContactsByName ? We cannot fetch or cache 20,000 contacts.

I saw a similar question which is unanswered [ContactsApp Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761157/contactsapp-performance#)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known issue. Check this [page](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1514) for more information. Unfortunately, as you can see, I don't see an official fix available for this yet.

Until then, the only workaround I can think of would be a little bit in parallel to some of the advice given [here](http://www.steegle.com/google-products/google-apps-script-faq). Divide your contacts into groups of smaller number and query those accordingly. Using and creating several [ContactGroups](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact-group) in this case might give you a better turn-around time.

Comment: It is an annoying issue. Thanks for the tips !!